# How do I bring an object one step forward in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

[image]

I want to bring the circle forward only one step, so it ends up between the green shapes. Please refer to the image if it's unclear what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Choose object
2. Hit <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (At least on a mac).

And <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>[</kbd> on Windows

Depending on your system, use these steps however many times you need to reach your desired effect.

Comment: You might need to repeat the keyboard shortcut a number of times, as the circle will need to 'pass' a number of different objects in front of it.

Comment: You could also Right CLick > Arrange > Bring Forward OR  Right Click > Arrange > Bring to Front and then Send Backward. Keyboard shortcuts are certainly quicker but if you're stumbling this way you can be sure that you've hit the button ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have CS5 for Mac and it is <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to `bring forward` (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to `send backwards`). 
You can find the menu item under `Object > Arrange`.

Alternatively, give each element a meaningful name in the `Layers` palette, select the layer and drag it to the desired position.

Comment: It's also `Ctrl+[` and `Ctrl+]` for Windows. Valuable advice about the titlling in the `Layers` palette!

Comment: You can add `Shift` to each of these to to `bring to front` and `send to back` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have the green ribbon in a single object. If that's the case you should separate the front of it (the green rectangle in the middle) from everything beyond the fold (if seen going from the middle to the outside). Once you have it in separate objects my fastest option is to select the green rectangle, Cut it (Ctrl/Cmd + X) and Paste In Front (Ctrl/Cmd + F). Then pick the folds, group each side in a single object and repeat the same but pasting behind. Would be: Select the folds, Cout it (Ctrl/Cmd + X) and Paste Behind (Ctrl/Cmd +B)